# SAS Data Sets on SharePoint

Tags: sas

I'm an IT person supporting researchers who use SAS. We have recently migrated most users storage from on-premises SMB shares to MS Teams. The question has arisen whether it's possible to keep SAS Data Sets in Teams storage (Sharepoint library), then access them via the synced library.

Are there any pitfalls to this approach? Any steps that could/should be taken to ensure there are no problems?

Comment: What do you mean by access?  Are you running SAS locally on your PC or remotely on some SAS server?  What operating system is the server using?  What did you try so far?

Comment: The research assistants will have SAS installed locally on their machines. I believe it will just be the basic SAS install. I don't know any more than than, but if there are other questions I should ask, let me know.

Comment: Is your SharePoint set up with automatic versioning and backups? How does that affect the SAS data sets? I've had issues when trying to use DropBox or One Drive as an automatic folder historically as the versioning and backups means they sometimes change the underlying name but not the displayed names which caused issues for me.

Comment: Yes, versioning is enabled. This is a Sharepoint online library (no on-prem components). We're going to try it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not ideal. SAS 9.4 accesses data through a concept called a libname. A libname is a location where data that SAS can access is stored. SAS 9.4 stores data in .sas7bdat files, but it can also [access a large variety of other databases natively](https://support.sas.com/en/software/sas-access.html#80efa431-3976-4a78-9f46-c5ada7825032).

If your users can [set up Sharepoint as a shared network disk](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53), SAS can work with it as if it is local. If not, your users will need to download the .sas7bdat files to their system locally, then re-upload it back to Sharepoint using the [Sharepoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest). [SAS can do this through code](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2020/07/09/sas-programming-office-365-onedrive/).

There really is no issue with it other than a convenience factor. It's not as ideal as a shared disk or database access, but it can work in theory.

If they decide to mount it as a network drive, I would add the caveat that they should *not* use Sharepoint as a place to store temporary data with high read/write speeds. In fact, I'd make it read-only to prevent them from doing so. If they need to pull the data locally then they can do so with libname access.

Comment: I don't want to have them set the library up as a shared drive, as that method is "legacy technology"; typically we use the "Sync" method recommended in that is described in the article you linked. Would you recommend against using the sync method?

Comment: I think that'd be perfectly okay. I don't know much about Teams' logic for when to sync files being constantly changed, but I'd imagine it's smart enough to wait a certain amount of time before starting a sync as the file is changed.

Comment: I think I'm going to recommend that they create a backup copy of the dataset just in case something doesn't play nice, but have them try with the sync option. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with that. sas7bdat files are designed to be read & written to randomly. In this situation, I would download the .sas7bdat files to my local drive and work with them there. So long as the user understands that it's in Sharepoint for data storage only and can be downloaded/manipulated on their local machine, it should work great. I would have them treat it similar to a .csv file that needed to be imported into SAS.